# How to vertically align an equation with three "sides"

Tags: equations, vertical-alignment

I am trying to add this to latex, but can't find how to do it.
I tried using

```
    \begin {align*}
        x+1 &=  y   &=  x   \\
        x   &=  y+1 &=  x   \\
    \end {align*}
```

but it doesn't work..
Also the {equation} only works for 2 sides
Any ideas?
[image]

Comment: How do you mean " the {equation} only works for 2 sides Any ideas?" ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems you're looking for `alignat`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{alignat*}{5}
       && x+1 &=  y   &&=  x   \\
       && x   &=  y+1 &&=  x   \\
\end{alignat*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: My thoughts exactly =) The only downside is the poor spacing around the second = signs, y + 1= x is very bad with that spacing between the 1 and the =, do you know how that can be fixed, possibly a nice `&{}=`?

Comment: @Au101 You're right, it was not pretty. Now it's slightly better, I hope.

Comment: Yes that's much better! I'd give you another +1 if I had another to give :P I was also wondering about `&&` but I didn't have enough confidence never actually having  used `alignat` myself. I was about to start experimenting, but you already answered, so I thought a comment would be better =)

Comment: @Au101 I also try to avoid this as much as possible. Especially if the equation reads `x+1=...=x` ;-)